# Inverted Index using a dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe, inverted-index

I have a dataframe as follows

| document | content |
| --- | --- |
| Ancient Egypt | Ancient Egypt was a civilization of ancient North Africa,... |
| Nile River | The Nile is a major north flowing river in northeastern Africa... |

I need to create an inverted index system to give me the words and their particular document name.

For an example

```
{'a': ['Ancient Egypt'],
 'Egypt': ['Ancient Egypt'],
 'is': ['Ancient Egypt  ', 'Nile River']}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `df` your dataframe you could do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inv_index = defaultdict(list)
for doc, words in zip(
        df.document,
        df.content.str.findall(r"\w+").map(set)
    ):
    for word in words:
        inv_index[word].append(doc)
```

Result - `inv_index` - for

```
df =
        document                                                         content
0  Ancient Egypt  Ancient Egypt was a civilization of ancient North Africa ,...
1     Nile River  The Nile is a major north flowing river in northeastern Africa
```

is

```
{
    'Africa': ['Ancient Egypt', 'Nile River'],
    'Ancient': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'Egypt': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'Nile': ['Nile River'],
    'North': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'The': ['Nile River'],
    'a': ['Ancient Egypt', 'Nile River'],
    'ancient': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'civilization': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'flowing': ['Nile River'],
    'in': ['Nile River'],
    'is': ['Nile River'],
    'major': ['Nile River'],
    'north': ['Nile River'],
    'northeastern': ['Nile River'],
    'of': ['Ancient Egypt'],
    'river': ['Nile River'],
    'was': ['Ancient Egypt']
}
```

Comment: @N-Sam If this was helpful please consider accepting/upvoting (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))